# Can TLS session resumption work after client dropped connection & reconnected to server?

Tags: ssl, openssl, handshake

I'm developing a sensor node and investigating TLS/OpenSSL. The network the node runs behind could drop and reconnect a lot. The node has limited data plan so data overhead is the key where TLS handshake is a big contributor as I understand.

Can session resumption be used after each network drop & reconnection? Or full handshake is needed in this case?

Comment: Well that's what session resumption means. Resuming a session.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Information Security Stack Exchange](http://security.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306).